# MATLAB: Running a .bat in parallel: multiple working directories possible?

Tags: matlab, batch-file, parallel-processing

I am running a .bat file using the command `system` (or `dos`) in a `parfor` loop in Matlab 2013a. Is there a way to change in which directory the command gets executed? So far it seems that it is always the current (working) directory. Another option would be to change the working directory inside the parfor loop, but that would mean having multiple working directories at the same time, which doesn't seem to be possible. The reason I do this is that I have one Simpack model and want to run several different simulations at the same time. In serial for-loop I can do this by copying the simulation specification to the Simpack folder one-at-a-time, but in parallel this must be changed.

```
parfor i=1:2
    ...
    cd(path_model_main_temp_i);
    system('C:\SIMPACK\SIMPACKv8.9\s_8904\simpack\com\spck.bat simpack integ modelname');
    copyfile(path_results_temp_i, path_results{i});
end
```

This snippet doesn't work, but is it the right direction?

EDIT: It turns out there was a different problem with my code. It is possible to have a `cd` command inside a parfor loop.

Comment: I am guessing here, as I don't have Matlab, so I have not put it as a formal answer, but maybe try `system('cd somewhere & C:\SIMPACK...')` which should allow THE SEPARATE PROCESS created by `system()` to have its own distinct directory.

Comment: So simple! Your suggestion works nicely, thank you. I will also try Edric's approach below, but my problem is actually already solved.

Comment: I'll add it as a full-blown answer, since it works :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing directory within the process created by the `system()` command - which is fine as it is a new, and distinct process, it can have its own directory.

Something like this:

```
system('cd somewhere & C:\SIMPACK...');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track here. One thing you could do use `getCurrentTask` to work out where to put that directory. For example, something like this:

```
parfor idx = 1:2
    t = getCurrentTask();
    if isempty(t)
       % running on the client - use tempdir
       d = tempdir();
    else
       % on a worker - make a subdirectory using task ID
       d = fullfile(tempdir(), num2str(t.ID));
       mkdir(d);
    end

    cd(d);
    pwd
    % do stuff
end
```

Comment: I see that it is indeed possible to have more working directories "at the same time" in the parfor loop. There was a different problem with my original code not related to this. Thanks for your answer, but I will still go with the option of adding a `cd` command into `system` because it looks cleaner to me.